# Decode rotory encoder reports

Tags: report, reverse, encoder

I am reverse engineering the serial protocol for a console and it has been relatively straight forward until I got to decoding the reports for a frequency control that consists of a small knob with a larger outer knob.

The hardware has two rotary encoders that drive the position event reports.

The console uses a serial ack/nak protocol that continuously streams reports in a packet format that has the following attributes:

1. Lead byte is an 0xA5
2. Payload Data byte values do not exceed a value of 0x7F, zero is allowed.
3. Checksum is computed by XOR’ing the payload bytes.
4. After resetting the console the output repeats every twenty clicks of the small knob.
5. After resetting the console the output repeats every ten clicks of the large knob.
6. Output data is variable based on the position of the other knob, so the report is for both knobs.
7. Clicking the same knob counter-clockwise, returns the previous event report.
8. The event report ID value is 0x0C.
9. In other types of event reports the third byte is the overflow of the second byte.

Small knob alone after console reset:

0C 0C 5B //index 00
0C 11 5B //index 01
0C 16 5B //index 02
0C 1B 5B //index 03
0C 20 5B //index 04
0C 25 5B //index 05
0C 2A 5B //index 06
0C 2F 5B //index 07
0C 50 5A //index 08
0C 55 5A //index 09
0C 5A 5A //index 10
0C 5F 5A //index 11
0C 64 5A //index 12
0C 69 5A //index 13
0C 6E 5A //index 14
0C 73 5A //index 15
0C 78 5A //index 16
0C 7D 5A //index 17
0C 02 5B //index 18
0C 07 5B //index 19

Large knob after console reset:

0C 0C 5B //index 00
0C 70 5B //index 01
0C 6C 54 //index 02
0C 50 55 //index 03
0C 34 56 //index 04
0C 18 57 //index 05
0C 7C 57 //index 06
0C 60 58 //index 07
0C 44 59 //index 08
0C 28 5A //index 09

Console reset followed by first rotating large and small knobs counter-clockwise one position. Then rotating the large knob clockwise one position, followed by the small knob.

Large Knob - Small Knob
0C 28 5A - 0C 23 5A //Index -1 rotate counter-clockwise one position
0C 07 5B - 0C 0C 5B //Index 00
0C 70 5B - 0C 75 5B //Index 01
0C 71 54 - 0C 76 54 //Index 02
0C 5A 55 - 0C 5F 55 //Index 03
0C 43 56 - 0C 48 56 //Index 04
0C 2C 57 - 0C 31 57 //Index 05
0C 15 58 - 0C 1A 58 //Index 06
0C 7E 58 - 0C 03 59 //Index 07
0C 67 59 - 0C 08 59 //Index 08
0C 6C 59 - 0C 71 59 //Index 09
0C 55 5A - 0C 5A 5A //Index 10
0C 3E 5B - 0C 43 5B //Index 11
0C 3F 54 - 0C 44 54 //Index 12
0C 28 55 - 0C 2D 55 //Index 13
0C 11 56 - 0C 16 56 //Index 14
0C 7A 56 - 0C 7F 56 //Index 15
0C 63 57 - 0C 68 57 //Index 16
0C 4C 58 - 0C 51 58 //Index 17
0C 35 59 - 0C 3A 59 //Index 18
0C 1E 5A - 0C 23 5A //Index 19
0C 07 5B - 0C 0C 5B //Index 20
0C 70 5B - 0C 75 5B //Index 21
0C 71 54 - 0C 76 54 //Index 22
0C 5A 55 - 0C 5F 55 //Index 23
0C 43 56 - 0C 48 56 //Index 24
0C 2C 57 - 0C 31 57 //Index 25
0C 15 58 - 0C 1A 58 //Index 26
0C 7E 58 - 0C 03 59 //Index 27
0C 67 59 - 0C 08 59 //Index 28
0C 6C 59 - 0C 71 59 //Index 29
0C 55 5A - 0C 5A 5A //Index 30
0C 3E 5B - 0C 43 5B //Index 31
0C 3F 54 - 0C 44 54 //Index 32
0C 28 55 - 0C 2D 55 //Index 33
0C 11 56 - 0C 16 56 //Index 34
0C 7A 56 - 0C 7F 56 //Index 35
0C 63 57 - 0C 68 57 //Index 36
0C 4C 58 - 0C 51 58 //Index 37
0C 35 59 - 0C 3A 59 //Index 38
0C 1E 5A - 0C 23 5A //Index 39
0C 07 5B - 0C 0C 5B //Index 40

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out.

It helps to decode the results as a decimal value, at which point a pattern fell into place.

Bit of a weird rotator value to account for due to the 0x7f payload value roll over.